# Access $scope from $rootScope by invoking the method defined in the $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a method defined on the $rootScope

```
$rootScope.method = function(value){
    // wanna give this value to `$scope.value` below:
};
```

And I invoke it from an entirely another $scope

```
app.controller('some', function($scope){
    $scope.value = null;    
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="some">
    <input ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="method(value)" >Click</button>
</div>
```

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to access the localized $scope from the method defined on $rootScope and alter its property?

I thought `this` will work <strike>but it doesn't</strike>

```
$rootScope.method = function(value){
    this.value = value // "this" is not the $scope
};
```

---

**edit**: Actually it does work. Just found out after I added this demo script that it does indeed work as I hoped

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.method = function(value) {
      this.changedValue = 'changed ' + value;
    }
  })
  .controller('some', function($scope) {
    // $scope.changedValue = 'not working';
  })
  .controller('someOther', function($scope) {
    $scope.changedValue = 'this should not change';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="main">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="some">
    <input ng-model="value"></input>
    <button ng-click="method(value)">Click</button>
    {{changedValue}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="someOther">
    {{changedValue}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just return the value from your method and assign it to $scope.value?

Comment: Oh Damn, actually it does work! (`this` ***is*** the `$scope`), I was just messing something else up.

Answer (score 2):

scope is a hierarchical tree with rootScope sitting on the top with controller scopes as child scopes. If you alter a value attached to the rootscope it would be available to both controllers ie if in ControllerA you set $rootscope.value = 1, controllerB can access $rootScope.value.

However it is not advised to attach values to the rootScope if you can avoid it. It is seen as bad practice in angular similar to setting global values in javascript.

A better way would be to create a service and inject it into both controllers. This service could contain any methods or values needed by both controllers. You can adjust a value in the service using a method defined in controllerA and access the service value in controllerB.

Alternatively you nan use the $broadcast to trigger a custom event. This travels down the scope chain so in controllerA:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('CUSTOM_EVENT_NAME', args);
```

controllerB

```
$scope.$on('CUSTOM_EVENT_NAME', function(ev, args) {
  //some code here
  //args are those passed from controllerA
});
```

but I would recommend a service as the better way

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
$rootScope.method = function(value){
    // wanna give this value to `$scope.value` below:
   $rootScope.value=value;
};


app.controller('some', function($scope,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.value = null;    
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="some">
    <input ng-model="value">
    <button ng-click="method(value)" >Click</button>
</div>
```